# I need help with a python script I am trying to adapt for a specific need

Tags: python

I am a total newbie with Python, I normally use Perl.

I have an Arduino wired up with some servos I use to control a web cam, the script in question works perfect, the servos receive the instruction and do what they should:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import serial

    usbport = '/dev/ttyACM0'

    # Set up serial baud rate
    ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 9600, timeout=1)


    def move(servo, angle):
        '''Moves the specified servo to the supplied angle.

        Arguments:
        servo
          the servo number to command, an integer from 1-4
        angle
         the desired servo angle, an integer from 0 to 180

    (e.g.) >>> servo.move(2, 90)
           ... # "move servo #2 to 90 degrees"'''

    if (0 <= angle <= 180):
       ser.write(chr(255))
       ser.write(chr(servo))
       ser.write(chr(angle))
    else:
        print "Servo angle must be an integer between 0 and 180.\n"
```

Basically the command for the above script is:

```
    python
    import servo
    servo.move(1, 180)
```

I have converted the script to accept command line input, however the program does not seem to work. can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong, here is my version:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import serial
    import sys

    try:
            servo = int(sys.argv[1])
            angle = int(sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError:
            print ('a servo and angle are required')
    sys.exit(2)

    # Set up serial baud rate
    usbport = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 9600, timeout=1)

    def move(servo, angle):
        '''Moves the specified servo to the supplied angle.

    Arguments:
        servo
          the servo number to command, an integer from 1-4
        angle
          the desired servo angle, an integer from 0 to 180

    (e.g.) >>> servo.move(2, 90)
           ... # "move servo #2 to 90 degrees"'''

    if (0 <= angle <= 180):
        ser.write(chr(255))
        ser.write(chr(servo))
        ser.write(chr(angle))
    else:
        print "Servo angle must be an integer between 0 and 180. You typed:"
        print servo
        print angle
    move(servo, angle)
```

Basically the command for the above script is:

```
    servo.py 1 180
```

I know the script works as it should as if I tell it to do a 1 181 I get the error that the angle is out of range, so I'm totally puzzled as to why the info is not passed to the serial/arduino.

Many thanks for any help and sorry for the long winded post.

Gilbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why adapt the original script? Just use this:

```
import servo
servo.move(int(argv[1]), int(argv[2]))
```

I'm not sure whether this happened when pasting code into stackoverflow, but the indenting is flawed on multiple places. Please check this too :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, yes it makes sense. Although how would you call this from the CLI without entering the python interface. Also, how are you suppose to type servo and angle after servo.move(int(argv[1]), int(argv[2])) ??

Answer (score 2):

Beside [@combatdave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845026/i-need-help-with-a-python-script-i-am-trying-to-adapt-for-a-specific-need/6845188#6845188), on this part:

```
try:
        servo = int(sys.argv[1])
        angle = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
        print ('a servo and angle are required')
sys.exit(2)

# Set up serial baud rate
```

You should indend sys.exit(2) too. Because of this, the program exits right after getting arguments.

Comment: Hi, the indent is wrong because of the way I input the code, on the original file, it is correct.

Comment: Then, could you please post the correct code, so that we can look for errors?

Comment: I have put the code in a file here: http:www.sharpnet.co.uk/tmp/servo.py Thanks. (PS. is that normal I don't get notified of the replies?)

Comment: Sorry for the post above, stupid website treats return as "add comment" (?!) I have put the code in a file here: http:www.sharpnet.co.uk/tmp/servo.txt Thanks. (PS. is that normal I don't get notified of the replies?)

Comment: I don't know hos this site works, I never get a notification and seems that people are too busy to bother about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your indentation after the function definition is wrong. It should be:

```
def move(servo, angle):
    '''Moves the specified servo to the supplied angle.

    Arguments:
        servo
          the servo number to command, an integer from 1-4
        angle
          the desired servo angle, an integer from 0 to 180

    (e.g.) >>> servo.move(2, 90)
           ... # "move servo #2 to 90 degrees"'''

    if (0 <= angle <= 180):
        ser.write(chr(255))
        ser.write(chr(servo))
        ser.write(chr(angle))
    else:
        print "Servo angle must be an integer between 0 and 180. You typed:"
        print servo
        print angle
```

(Note how the if...else block is indented)

Comment: Hi, the indent is wrong because of the way I input the code, on the original file, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong basically.

See this snippet:

```
try:
        servo = int(sys.argv[1])
        angle = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
        print ('a servo and angle are required')
sys.exit(2)
```

The `sys.exit(2)` call is always executed! So the program does nothing.

Comment: Hi, the indent is wrong because of the way I input the code, on the original file, it is correct

Comment: then please fix the indenting of the code in the question. In Python indenting matters and we cannot help you if we do not have the correct code.

Comment: I have put the code in a file here: http:www.sharpnet.co.uk/tmp/servo.txt Thanks. (PS. is that normal I don't get notified of the replies?)