# Python script and cgi throws an error

Tags: python, cgi

Thanks to [nightcracker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565635/nightcracker) for his suggestion on [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845026/i-need-help-with-a-python-script-i-am-trying-to-adapt-for-a-specific-need), it works!

I have another issue now, I am trying to make this work via a cgi Form to pilot the cameras from a Browser.

The script goes like this:

[link to the script](http://www.sxg.com/tmp/servocgi.txt)

the error I get is:

[link to the python error](http://www.sxg.com/tmp/servocgipy.html)

So if any of you know what the problem is I am all eyes.

Thanks!

Comment: Lol, I actually clicked on this question, only to see my name :D

Comment: Please put the code and errors in the question not as links that might fgi away

Comment: Hi, I tried to insert code on this site but it is not satisfactory, when I select the "code" tag on the editor a line saying "insert code here" comes up but if I paste the code only the first line get inserted as code, the remainder is formatted as normal text :-( . I don't know why but I don't really fancy typing the whole code by hand again. It must be me, either I am too clever or stupid to get it.

Comment: @Bib: you have to write or copy/paste your code. Then you select(highlight) it with your mouse. Then you click on the code tag {}. This will format all the block selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that integers do not have a method of `move`.

This is happening because `servo` is an integer (see line 13). When you do `servo.move(...)` you are calling a member method of the integer class... which does not exist. Perhaps you have another variable called `servo` somewhere else and you overwrote it?

Comment: Hi, thanks, that fixed the problem, I had input var servo called the same as the function, stupid really.